# Get all content outside of body html tag

Tags: php, regex

I have a script which gets the inside of a body tag but not the outside, and I require both. I've searched around and I can only find code to get the inside of the body tag, not the outside. Any help? I could explode the string with "body" but the problem is, the attributes of the body tag can change and that's what I'm stumped on -_-

Comment: regexes on html? this is madness! Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead.

Comment: [Here's an SO article on why regex is a bad idea for HTML parsing.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: @Matt: You might have linked http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/135078, to back MarcB's statement :-)

Comment: @Bergi +1 for finding more ammo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really want to use Regex to search outside of the `<body>...</body>`, try with this(PHP):

```
/<body[^>]*+>([^<]*+(?:(?!<\/?+body)<[^<]*+)*+)<\/body>/
```

and keep start and end position from search result, use these for search outside of body tag.